# makefile not rebuilding after make build

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

makefile will build and put the .o files in a dir one time, run one time and clean one time. But after i clean it, it will not allow me to rebuild.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -lm
TARGET=out

C_SRCS := \
    $(wildcard *.cpp) \
HDRS := \
    $(wildcard*.h) \


OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp, bin/%.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))



build: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS)

bin/%.o: %.cpp $(HDRS)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
    rm $(TARGET)
    rm -r bin

run:
    ./$(TARGET) input.txt output.txt
```

The files used in this compile correctly just the make file is inccorect

Comment: Ouch, there's a lot wrong with this Makefile ... check out [Paul's Laws](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) or start with a demo project (like [mine](https://github.com/o11c/makefile-demo/blob/master/Makefile) for example)

Comment: what can i do to fix it, i am very new to using makefiles

Comment: Please show us what you see when you try to rebuild.

Comment: You probably didn't post your real makefile, because the one posted already fails to compile a simple C++ hello world example.